# Fullcalendar - Unable to color eventSources with eventColor

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to color two EventSources differently using eventColor and it isn't working.

```
jQuery("#calendar").fullCalendar({ 
    eventSources: [
        {
            events: events1,
            eventColor: '#f00'
        },
        {
            events: events2
        }
    ]
});
```

event1 should have a red background, but it is not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/hhynzokh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **color** vs **eventColor**

http://jsfiddle.net/hhynzokh/1/

```
jQuery("#calendar").fullCalendar({ 
    eventSources: [
        {
            events: events1,
            color: '#f00'
        },
        {
            events: events2
        }
    ]
});
```